# MEAN Stack, Updating the user from a different module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, module, meanjs

I have a problem with updating/saving users after running a client-side function that adds on a _id (of another module called course) to the user. An overview of what I have is a CRUD module called courses, and I would like for a user to be able to join that course, so the function to do so is as follows 
(courses.client.controller.js):

```
    $scope.joinCourse = function() {

        var course = $scope.course;
        var user = $scope.authentication.user; 
        var flag = false;
        if ($scope.insertedCCode === course.courseCode) {
            for (var i in user.joinedCourses) {
                if (user.joinedCourses[i] === course._id) {
                    flag = true;  // Already joined the course
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                user.joinedCourses.push(course._id);
            }
            course.$updateUser(function(response) {
                $scope.success = true;
                Authentication.user = response;
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.error = response.data.message;
            });
    }
```

updateUser is a server-side function I made to save the new changes made to user, though I am not sure if that is a proper way of adding or using back-end functions. It's the exact same thing as when updating for a profile change. I found that it saves the course if I update my profile after joining the course.

```
exports.updateUser = function(req, res) {
// Init Variables
var user = req.user;
var message = null;

// For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
delete req.body.roles;

if (user) {
    // Merge existing user
    user = _.extend(user, req.body);
    user.updated = Date.now();  // Join date??

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                } else {
                    res.json(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
} else {
    res.status(400).send({
        message: 'User is not signed in'
    });
}};
```

When I run the joinCourse function, it gives an error of TypeError: undefined is not a function at Scope.$scope.joinCourse, at the line where course.$updateUser is called (from block 1). So I passed in the same things as user.$update needs, why does it not work?

To boil it all down, I'm trying to update a user from a different module and I'm not sure on how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!